# Solaris using sequence generator at the beginning of each new line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I created a script that extracts data from a database and loads it to a csv file. I am using `SunOS hstz1454 5.10` system. I am trying to do a sequence at the beginning of each line following with a commma.

Data looks like this below:

```
1,1,1535,0,1,Y,Y
1,1,1535,10,2,Y,Y
1,1,1535,20,1,Y,Y
1,1,1535,30,2,Y,Y
1,1,1535,40,1,Y,Y
```

I want my csv file to generate a sequence number at the beginning og each line follow by a comma:

```
1,1,1,1535,0,1,Y,Y
2,1,1,1535,10,2,Y,Y
3,1,1,1535,20,1,Y,Y
4,1,1,1535,30,2,Y,Y
5,1,1,1535,40,1,Y,Y
```

Here is my code only prints `1` and does not increment, how can I increment on each new line?

```
for fname in conv2016_02_cos_speed2percent_data_migration.csv
do
  echo "adds a seq number on each line for $fname"
  sed 's/.*/1,&/' $fname > tmp.tmp 
  mv tmp.tmp $fname
done
```

Comment: Are you using Linux or SunOS? Title metions linux, the question sunos/solaris...

Comment: I have SunOS hsdz0150 5.10 Generic_150400-20 sun4v sparc sun4v, I am new to shell scripting so I was not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `nl`:

```
nl -s, -w1 file
```

This will add an incrementing number to the beginning of each line. `-s,` specifies that the number and the rest of the line should be separated by a comma. `-w1` specifies the number of characters to be used for the line number.

---

**Edit**: As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) pointed out in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249833/solaris-using-sequence-generator-at-the-beginning-of-each-new-line/249839#comment429997_249839), the `-w1` flag cuts the numbers with more than 1 digits. This may be a bug in Solaris' implementation of the `nl` utillity. Also, you may want to number special line content (`-d $'\n\n'`) and emtpy lines (-ba):

```
NL='
'
nl -s, -ba -d "$NL$NL" file
```

---

The output (with `GNU coreutils 8.12.197`):

```
$ nl -s, -ba -d "$NL$NL" file
     1,4,2,64,1088,80,1,Y,Y
     2,5,2,64,1088,95,2,Y,Y
     3,8,2,1088,39813120,10,12,Y,Y
     4,6,2,1088,39813120,0,2,Y,Y
     5,7,2,1088,39813120,5,1,Y,Y
     6,8,2,1088,39813120,10,2,Y,Y
```

---

In your script it would then look like:

```
NL='
'
for fname in conv2016_02_cos_speed2percent_data_migration.csv; do
  nl -s, -ba -d "$NL$NL" "$fname"  > tmp.tmp && mv tmp.tmp "$fname"
done
```

Comment: To support arbitrary line content, with `nl`, you generally need to add `-ba -d $'\n\n'`, otherwise it won't number empty lines or treat some special line content specially.

Comment: @Chaos this only went from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2...and etc. It did not print 10,11,12 and so on

Comment: I'd recommend using `mktemp` to generate a guaranteed-unique temporary filename lest parallel invocations wipe out or corrupt data.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @yescobar1, yes that seems to be a conformance bug in Solaris `nl` implementation (also in Solaris 11) or an oversight in the POSIX spec (which AFAIU does not allow that truncation) as Solaris nl likely descends directly from the original SVR2 implementation.

Comment: @yescobar1 The `-w1` argument looks to be limiting the line number to one character.  I'd recommend trying `-nln` instead of `-w1` per the man page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/nl-1.html#scrolltoc.

Comment: @yescobar1 You can omit the `-w1` from the command. I don't have a solaris here to confirm your behaviour with the numbers, but with `GNU coreutils 8.12.197` the number go normal.

Comment: @yescobar1 *how do I do that?*  Something like `TMPFILE={backtick}mktemp -p . -t tmpXXXXXX.tmp{backtick}` (replace {backtick} with actual backticks in your script...) should work. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/mktemp-1.html#scrolltoc

Comment: @AndrewHenle & @Chaos once I removed -w1 and used -nln it worked. Also, it shows a couple of white spaces at least 5 white spaces in between the sequence number and comma I don't know if this will affect when I insert into a table `1         ,1,1,1535,0,1,Y,Y`

Comment: @yescobar1 The `-nrn` argument will right-justify the line number and should eliminate the trailing space.  I don't know offhand if the Solaris version will trim any possible leading spaces.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that removed the trailing white spaces but it added a few white spaces at the beginnig of the sequence number but I don't think that should matter. Thanks so much.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, [issue raised on the Austin group mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11789)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way with awk:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{print NR, $0}' < "$fname" > tmp && mv -- tmp "$fname"
```

and cat with sed

```
cat -n < "$fname" |
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*/\1,/' > tmp &&
mv -- tmp "$fname"
```

On Solaris, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed|awk` (or `command -p sed|awk` if using a POSIX shell or adapt `$PATH` to get a standard environment as detailed in `standards(5)`).

Comment: Hey people, upvote @chaos's answer

Comment: @Stéphane, thanks for the reference to that man page.